# Change the background of a view controller using a subclassed UIButton in a separate file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner to Swift/iOS programming. I'm trying to do things programmatically. I created a subclass of a UIButton in a separate swift file. My objective is to just change the background of the underlying ViewController.

CustomButton.swift

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        self.setTitle("Press Me", for: .normal)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        // Button Action
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        // Verify the method is called when the button is pressed
        self.setTitle("Pressed", for: .normal)
        // Change the background color for the ViewController
        let vc = ViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    let myButton = CustomButton()

    fileprivate func addElements() {
        view.addSubview(myButton)

        myButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        myButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
        myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
        myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -400).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        addElements()
    }


}
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work or what I'm missing.

Comment: Based on your code `CustomButton` would need a reference to the parent view.  You could use the button's `superview` property, but personally, I'd add a target in `ViewController` to respond to the button and let the `ViewController` take care of it

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you are creating a brand new VC here:

```
// Change the background color for the ViewController
let vc = ViewController() // This VC is not the same one as the one that's presented on screen
vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
```

---

Your custom `UIButton` do not and **should not** know about the view controller that controls it. The VC should handle this.

Your `UIButton` subclass should just be:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        self.setTitle("Press Me", for: .normal)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

You should add your VC as a target for the button, in the VC.

What I mean is:

```
// in viewDidLoad
let button = CustomButton(...)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)

// ...

func didTapButton() {
    view.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Comment: Ah I see...Putting the addTarget... and the associated function in the ViewController file worked. Thank You.

Comment: @Yetimate If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of `UIViewController` then you have to pass that controller.

Follow these steps:-

**1st step - Create a custom button class and create a `viewController` variable type of `UIViewController` so you can assign the specific controller to change the background of `UIViewController` color.**

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        viewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

**2nd step - UIViewController code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: CustomButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.viewController = self //Assigning controller using self keyword

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the good way to do, don't give `customButton` a reference to it `parentController`. `CustomButton` inherit from `UIButton` so you can `addTarget(_)` directly from the view controller :)

Comment: He wants to change the color of a controller so `Custombutton` property code should be in `CustomButton` own file. if he wants to implement not related to that particular class then is it ok to do in the button action method in `ViewController` file. The more you code split into write file the more you can understand

Answer (score 0):

- This is happening because your **ViewController instance** is changed. You are trying to change ViewController's backgroundcolor by creating new **instance** of it in your **buttonPressed()** method. So that the current instance of your ViewController and this newly created instance are different so background color is not changed.
- You can do it by adding **Notification** to your **ViewController** class and **post** this **Notification** in your button action that is **buttonPressed()**.
- Follow these steps as below:
- Add this code in your ViewController's **viewDidLoad()** :

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeBackgroundColor), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “load”), object: nil)`

- Add below function in your **ViewController.swift** file:

as -

```
func changeBackgroundColor() {
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple 
}
```

- Now post this above Notification in **buttonPressed()** as -    `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object:nil)`